# What's so interesting about the acceptance cone in fiber optics?

Tags: visible-light, fiber-optics

I'm reading about fiber optics and the concept of the acceptance cone.
[image]

I understand the concept, if you shine light into the fiber in an angle higher than the acceptance angle, the light won't be transmitted.

Why is that so interesting? Arent we always shining light direclty into the fiber? At zero angle?

Comment: The cables themselves aren't straight, so there will be reflection at some point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Arent we always shining light direclty into the fiber? At zero angle?

Actually, we aren't. Look [here](http://www.kimmon.com/datasheets/He-Cd%20catalog(E).pdf), for example. The commonly used He-Cd laser has a Beam width of anywhere between $\frac{1}{e^2}$ 0.5-2 mm. It means that if the intensity of the laser beam at the very center is $I_0$, the intensity 0.5-2mm away from the center, respectively, is $\frac{1}{e^2}\cdot I_0$. Furthermore, consider [beam divergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beam_divergence), which mean the beam actually widens as the laser beam travels.

Now consider a fiber. There are various sizes and types of fibers, but generally, the most *common* ones are of the order of tens to hundreds of micrometers. Note that this is **at least** an order of magnitude lower than the width of the laser beam, I just talked about.

How is this tackled in real life? The question is of course not too difficult: use lenses. However, lenses require precise alignment so that their focal point lies exactly at the start of your fiber. This is when acceptance cone comes into play, too.

In simpler words: unless you manage to place your lens at such a point that actually manages to "pack" as much of your laser light as possible into the fiber, you are not going to efficiently transmit it.